# How does "docker service rm" kills a service? Which signal does it send to the service?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

How does "docker service rm" kills a service? Which signal exactly does it send to the service?

Answer (score 0):

It should be calling the API's for `docker stop` against the container on the node where it's running. By default the `docker stop` will send a SIGTERM followed by a SIGKILL after 10 seconds if the container doesn't gracefully exit. You can see that 10 seconds in commands that don't respond to SIGTERM:

```sh
$ cat dc.tail.yml 
version: "3"

services:
  tail:
    image: busybox
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"

$ docker stack deploy -c dc.tail.yml tail
Creating network tail_default
Creating service tail_tail

$ docker service rm tail_tail
tail_tail

$ docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND               CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
9e06fbf70708   busybox:latest   "tail -f /dev/null"   16 seconds ago   Up 15 seconds             tail_tail.1.jr4j6sl4oad9fst5qey84rbb0

$ docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND               CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
9e06fbf70708   busybox:latest   "tail -f /dev/null"   19 seconds ago   Up 18 seconds             tail_tail.1.jr4j6sl4oad9fst5qey84rbb0

$ docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND               CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
9e06fbf70708   busybox:latest   "tail -f /dev/null"   21 seconds ago   Up 20 seconds             tail_tail.1.jr4j6sl4oad9fst5qey84rbb0

$ docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND               CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
9e06fbf70708   busybox:latest   "tail -f /dev/null"   23 seconds ago   Up 22 seconds             tail_tail.1.jr4j6sl4oad9fst5qey84rbb0

$ docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND               CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
9e06fbf70708   busybox:latest   "tail -f /dev/null"   25 seconds ago   Up 24 seconds             tail_tail.1.jr4j6sl4oad9fst5qey84rbb0

$ docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND               CREATED          STATUS                                PORTS     NAMES
9e06fbf70708   busybox:latest   "tail -f /dev/null"   26 seconds ago   Exited (137) Less than a second ago             tail_tail.1.jr4j6sl4oad9fst5qey84rbb0
```

The 137 exit code is 128+9, from the SIGKILL (signal 9).